# remove hours, minutes, seconds, from datetime c#

Tags: c#

I want remove hours minutes seconds from datetime c#. My code:

```
string dateFrom = "5/4/2019";
DateTime result = (DateTime)dateFrom.DecodeUrl().ConvertDateTime();
// result "5/4/2019 12:00:00 AM"
//the result i want "2019-04-05"
```

Comment: A `DateTime` is basically a fancy `Int64` counting ticks since `DateTime.MinValue`. There is **no way** to get a `DateTime` "without" hours, minutes, seconds etc. Even `result.Date` would only return a `DateTime`, where those "parts" are set to zero. Which is, what OP already gets. -- `"2019-04-05"` is a `string` representing a `DateTime` without those "parts" in a specific (ISO) format. To get that, use for example `result.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")`.

Comment: If you want to change format of date and want to use it then you can make it like
`string dateFrom = "5/4/2019";`

//below code will give you date format like "yyyy-MM-dd" so you will get "2019-04-05"

`var result = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
`
And after that you can use result for further process.

Comment: What do you want as result? A `string`? Than KalaiSelvan R's answer is your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could use Convert class to convert your string to datetime object then can pass your required string format in ToString() method.

```
string dateFrom = "5/4/2019";
string output = Convert.ToDateTime(dateFrom).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use **string format** to define any format you want to get output.
below are some **formats** you can reffer :-

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 05/29/2015
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") Friday, 29 May 2015 5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm:ss")    Friday, 29 May 2015 05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")   05/29/2015 05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm tt")    05/29/2015 05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy H:mm")    05/29/2015 5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") 05/29/2015 5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")    05/29/2015 05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("MMMM dd")    May 29
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss.fffffffK") 2015-05-16T05:50:06.7199222-04:00
DateTime.Now.ToString("ddd, dd MMM yyy HH’:’mm’:’ss ‘GMT’") Fri, 16 May 2015 05:50:06 GMT
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy’-‘MM’-‘dd’T’HH’:’mm’:’ss")  2015-05-16T05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")  05:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm tt")   05:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm")   5:50
DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm tt")    5:50 AM
DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")   05:50:06
DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy MMMM")  2015 May
```

Comment: Be aware that using `ToString` usually uses the Current(UI?)Culture (of the current thread), which may use a `DateTimeFormatInfo` with a different `DateSeparator`, day/month names etc. So results might be different.

Comment: See also [custom format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and [standard format specifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings).